# How to use response.redirect from aspx in vb.net?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

```
function temp() {
        <% Response.Redirect("TS.aspx?PPStartDate="+HttpUtility.UrlEncode(hdnPP.Value),true)%>
    }

<img alt="" class="style1" src="../Asps/Images/calendar.gif"   önclick="temp();" />
```

I'm calling this function on button onclick event from aspx which isn't working. Please share your ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do that!!!

You are trying to mix server-side code and client-side code.

The stuff in the `<% %>` will be executed as the HTML response is being constructed. The redirect will occur before the client even sees the HTML!

Instead, keep the whole thing on the client:

```
function temp() {
    location.href = "TS.aspx?PPStartDate=" + UrlEncode(hdnPP.Value);
}
```

Note that I'm not quite certain of the syntax for the JavaScript equivalent of UrlEncode, or whether hdnPP.Value will work the way you have your code written.

Comment: encodeURIComponent is javascript equivalent of UrlEncode